# How do i Hide an image after the animation images is done

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

```
    Monster1Hit = YES;
    Monster1.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode1.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode2.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode3.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode4.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode5.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode7.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode8.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode9.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode10.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode11.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode12.png"],
                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"Explode13.png"], nil];
    [Monster1 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    Monster1.animationDuration = 1;
    [Monster1 startAnimating];
```

I want the image to be hidden after the animation is complete to make it look like an explosion and the picture disappears.

Answer (score 0):

In the docs, you can see we have:

```
// for one cycle of images. default is number of images * 1/30th of a second (i.e. 30 fps)
@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
```

This is a property of the image view class.

Because you manually set this property, you can also create a timer and fire it after that duration.

Make it call a method that would hid the image view or anything else you need.

Put this code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(hideImageMethod) userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
```

before

```
[Monster1 startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to remove the `UIImageView` from your view hierarchy:

```
- (void)animationFinished:(NSObject *)notImportant {
    [Monster1 removeFromSuperview];
    // Or alternatively [Monster1 setHidden:YES];
}
```

And schedule that method to be called when the animation will be finished.

```
// Put this right before [Monster1 startAnimating]
[self performSelector:@selector(animationFinished:) withObject:nil
    afterDelay:Monster1.animationDuration];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any work you can call function after your animation duration like below

```
[self performSelector:@selector(animationDidFinish:) withObject:nil
    afterDelay:Monster1.animationDuration]; //Do whataver you want to do in animationDidFinish: and start animation again if you want
```